# How to grab a font-awesome icon in the li tag which is first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

The folders `aaa` `bbb` `ccc` and `ddd` are the main directories in this html structure. How can i disable (display;none) the font-awesome icon for the main directories only? For the main directories, the icon should not appear
PS: I can not change the classname because its dynamically generated for all the `li` tags!
This is my html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>aaa</li>
    <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>bbb</li>
    <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ccc
       <ul>
           <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subccc</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ddd
       <ul>
           <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subddd</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is making use of the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)** to set `display: none` on the top level (`ul > li > .fas`) icons, and then also making use of **[CSS specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** to additionally add a **more specific** selector for elements lower down the hierarchy.

Although both selectors will actually target the child icons, because there's a more specific selector applied which sets the icons as visible again, these elements will show up.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
ul > li > .fas {
  display: none;
}

ul li > ul .fas {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>aaa</li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>bbb</li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ccc
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subccc</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ddd
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subddd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider 2 selectors to achieve this:

```css
/*Hide all of them*/
ul li.treeview i {
  display: none;
}


/*Show the nested ones*/
ul ul li.treeview i {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>aaa</li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>bbb</li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ccc
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subccc</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ddd
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subddd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or with one selector but you should pay attention when changing the html:

```css
:not(.treeview) > ul > li.treeview > i {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>aaa</li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>bbb</li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ccc
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subccc</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>ddd
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i>subddd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick : }

```
ul:first-child > li {
display:none;
}
```

Hope it helped !